# Code is highlighted differently in firebug

Tags: firefox, firebug

if anyone could point me to the right direction or tell me what's wrong.

I googeld for a while but could not find any "firebug highlight options" or anything like that. The problem is: I would like firebug to highlight when I hover something with this blue and yellow color like picture bellow. (got the picture from the web)

[image: This is how I would like it]

Thats how it is looking at work, but now I'm at home and here it highlights only a border. 
See next pic.

[image: This is how it is and I don't like it]

It is FireFox 23.0.1

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you have the "Shade Box Model" HTML panel option checked?

Comment: @SimonLindholm Thanks Simon, that was it. If you write your comment as an answer I'd love to mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the "Shade Box Model" HTML panel option is checked.
[image: Shade Box Model option]

Answer (score 0):

The yellow is for the margin. If you don't have any margins, then you won't get the yellow bit.

As for the difference between the blue bit, you'll get the border effect from your second screenshot if you use the "inspect" button and then move the mouse around the page. You'll get the fully shaded blue effect if you use firebug's DOM tree to select the elements.

That's just kinda the way it works.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Sorry the pic wasn't the best before. Now I updated my question with a new pic with the div having a margin and a padding. the padding should be showing kinda purple but there is still just the border. you can point me to a link anywhere I will just get the border, no blue, no yellow, no purple... thanks for your help